# how to get deployments for selected machine in Azure devops deployment groups using rest api

Tags: azure-devops, azure-devops-rest-api, azure-devops-deploymentgroups

I am working on script to get deployment from Azure DevOps for selected Azure DevOps Deployment group and Selected target machine

following Used rest api url does not provide required data -

```
$connectionToken = ""

$Url1 = "https://dev.azure.com/{Org Name}{Project Name}/_apis/distributedtask/deploymentgroups? 
name={name}&api-version=6.0-preview.1"

$base64AuthInfo= 
[System.Convert]::ToBase64String([System.Text.Encoding]::ASCII.GetBytes(":$($connectionToken)"))

$json = Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $Url1 -Headers @{authorization = "Basic $base64AuthInfo"} -Method Get

$data = $json | ConvertTo-Json -Depth 100 

$data
```

What rest api url changes I need to do for getting required data ?

Comment: Hi @megha. Is there any update about this ticket? Feel free to let me know if the answer could give you some help.

Comment: @KevinLu-MSFT thank you so much. This works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> What rest api url changes I need to do for getting required data ?

You could try the following URL to get the deployment Jobs :

```
https://dev.azure.com/{OrganizationName}/{ProjectName}/_apis/distributedtask/deploymentgroups/{DeployGroup ID}/deploymentTargetJobRequests?targetId={TargetMachineID}&api-version=6.1-preview.1
```

You could get the `deploygroup id` and `target machine id` in the Azure Devops url:

[image]

mgid = `deploygroup id` machineid = `target machine id`.

Here is the Powershell Example:

```
$connectionToken = "PAT"

$Url1 = "https://dev.azure.com/{OrganizationName}/{ProjectName}/_apis/distributedtask/deploymentgroups/{DeployGroup ID}/deploymentTargetJobRequests?targetId={TargetMachineID}&api-version=6.1-preview.1"

$base64AuthInfo= [System.Convert]::ToBase64String([System.Text.Encoding]::ASCII.GetBytes(":$($connectionToken)"))

$json = Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $Url1 -Headers @{authorization = "Basic $base64AuthInfo"} -Method Get

$data = $json | ConvertTo-Json -Depth 100 

$data
```

**Result:**

[image]

Comment: is there any way to get older deployments ? This gives me only for resent months.